# Сделать reverse строки с сохранением множественных пробельных символов на своих местах используя StringJoiner

Tags: java, reverse

Метод должен переворачивать каждое слово в строке и включать сохранение длины входной строки "abc   " -> "cba   "). Если между словами и в конце есть пробелы, они должны сохранится на своих местах.

```
public String reverseString(String string) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : string.split(" ")) {
        stringBuilder.append(reverseWord(word)).append(" ");
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
}
```

Здесь метод trim()  не подходит, так как убирает все пробелы в конце. Нужно реализовать с использованием класа StringJoiner.
Кто знает, помогите , пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю что-то такое

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String original = "   abc ";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(original.trim());
    String updated = original.replace(original.trim(), sb.reverse().toString());

    System.out.println(new StringJoiner("", "[", "]").add(original));
    System.out.println(new StringJoiner("", "[", "]").add(updated));
  }
```

или если каждое слово

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String original = "   abc  123654  ";

    String reversed =
        List.of(original.trim().split(" ")).stream()
            .map(word -> new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    String updated = original.replace(original.trim(), reversed);

    System.out.println(new StringJoiner("", "[", "]").add(original));
    System.out.println(new StringJoiner("", "[", "]").add(updated));
  }
```

в методы сами переведёте если есть необходимость

Comment: спасибо! вы меня спасли )

Comment: Если помогло галочка снизу под стрелками